# Change Spotlight web search default keybindng

Tags: macos, keyboard, spotlight, search, keybindings

The default keybinding to search the web from Spotlight (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) is <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Is it possible to change it?  I haven't even found this keybinding documented on official [website](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/spotlight-keyboard-shortcuts-mh26783/10.14/mac/10.14). (macOS Mojave 10.14).